# How change admin login url in Codeigniter 1?

Tags: codeigniter

Im using codeigniter 1 for a web system I want to change admin login url to my custom login url

```
current url     - *http://siteUrl/admin/login*
Want to change  - *http://siteUrl/adlogin*
```

How can I change this using *config/router.php*

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make route in config/routes.php

```
$route['siteUrl/adlogin']='controllername/methodname';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create routes for Your New URL Like :

URL:
application_url/application/config/routes.php

```
$route['adlogin'] = 'admin/login;
```

Please try this solution for your problem.

Comment: Can you post your route file and also base_url ?

Answer (score 0):

Use That on Route Without parameter Pass

```
$route['adlogin'] = 'admin/login';
```

With parameter Use This..

```
$route['adlogin/(:any)'] = 'admin/login/$1';
```